# Idiom or phrasal verb meaning "give in his efforts"

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs, existentials

I'm facing to a little problem. 
To improve my English fluency I decided to learn some phrasal verbs, and practice them by writing short phrases. 
But here we are, it seems for me that the phrase below isn't as we can say "English"

> that's not after few tries the student should give in his efforts.

The meaning of "give in" is stop trying. I agree that it may have several different significations

All of all, does my question is grammatically correct?

Comment: "Give in" is closer to "surrender" than "stop trying". As in, "Luke, don't **give in** to hate," from *The Empire Strikes Back*. In that case, it means Luke should not let hate take over.

Comment: Interestingly (to me, anyway) your sentence has a hint of two different idioms:  You could quite properly say, "That's not to say that after a few tries, the student should throw in the towel."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the phrasal verb "give up" or "give up on" instead of "give in".  "Give up"'s direct object is a thing that is being given up.  "Give up on"'s direct object is a goal or method or effort that the subject is using, and is abandoning.  "Give in" usually does not take a direct object.

Also, the first part of the sentence is unclear.  Perhaps you meant:

> That does not mean that after only a few tries, the student should give up on his efforts.

By default, "give up" is an idiom that means "give up on one's efforts", so the sentence can be simplified to:

> That does not mean that after only a few tries, the student should give up.